# How to test for an empty, single-parented commit in Git?

Tags: git

I am scripting some one-way gateway procedure between an existing source control (Subversion) and Git. `git-svn` leaves many empty linear commits in its remote branches, because of excluded paths, and I want to exclude these from the resulting branch. At some point, I am getting a list of commits by SHA from `git cherry` that I need to toss to the target branch.

I want to exclude commits that are empty (those for which `git show` does not provide a diff, only a comment) and have one parent, i. e. not merges. What are the commands I could use in a script to do such a test? Low level porcelain is preferable, as it is suited for automated parsing.

I can rely on Git being of the latest version, currently have 2.6.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git rev-parse ${SHA}^1` tests for the first parent, `git rev-parse ${SHA}^2` tests for the second parent.  A merge commit will error when checking for `^2`.

A commit that introduces no changes will have a tree-SHA that is identical to its parent. `git rev-parse ${SHA}^{tree}` will give you the tree-SHA of the commit, then compare it to the tree of its parent - `${SHA}~1`

Comment: `${SHA}^{tree}` is wonderful, thanks! I do not understand the `git rev-list` part though. What I have is a list of SHA1s of commits, ready to cherry-pick. I just want to drop those that have no changes (that is solved thanks to your answer) **and** have one parent. So how do I test the single commit in question has one parent?

Comment: Test `git rev-parse ${SHA}^2`, if it exists then it is a merge.  Ill update the answer tomorrow

Comment: Another way to test for parents is to check the length of `git show --no-patch --pretty="%P"`. This command returns the SHA of _all_ parents, each separated by a space. If the command returns a string longer than the length of one SHA hash (40 characters), then you know it has more than one parent.

Since all parent SHAs are returned, this command can help with a few more things:

#1: Tell you if a commit is the first one (length of 0).
#2: Tell precisely how many parents there are (increases linearly).
#3: Provide input for `git merge-base` to find where the branches coincide again.